# Jenkins Linux Slave error: SEVERE: I/O error in channel channel

Tags: jenkins, slave

I am getting this error on all Linux servers try to start a Slave. The version isJenkins ver. 1.532.1. I didn't have this problem when I have another installation with Jenkins ver. 1.509.4.

I've read many posts on Internet regarding this issue, still have no clue to fix it. Almost want to remove this installation and install the older ver. 1.509.4 now.

Anyone can give some idea on how to debug this?

The jenkins.log:

```
Dec 20, 2013 9:38:24 AM jenkins.slaves.JnlpSlaveAgentProtocol$Handler$1 onClosed
WARNING: Channel reader thread: trmsrv43 for + trmsrv43 terminated
java.net.SocketException: Socket closed


bash-3.00$ java  -jar slave.jar -jnlpUrl htttp://name:8080/computer/trmsrv43/slave-agent.jnlp
20-Dec-2013 9:37:47 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener <init>
INFO: Jenkins agent is running in headless mode.
20-Dec-2013 9:37:47 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Locating server among [htttp://name:8080/, htttp://name:8080/]
20-Dec-2013 9:38:02 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connecting to name:45606
20-Dec-2013 9:38:02 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Handshaking
20-Dec-2013 9:38:02 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connected
20-Dec-2013 9:38:03 AM hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread run
SEVERE: I/O error in channel channel
java.io.IOException: Unexpected termination of the channel
        at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:50)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:48)
20-Dec-2013 9:38:03 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Terminated
20-Dec-2013 9:38:03 AM hudson.remoting.JarCacheSupport$1 run
WARNING: Failed to resolve a jar e42831c9e9138e2761253da84a096665
hudson.remoting.RemotingSystemException: hudson.remoting.ChannelClosedException: channel is already closed
caused by: hudson.remoting.ChannelClosedException: channel is already closed
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.send(Channel.java:516)
        at hudson.remoting.Request.call(Request.java:129)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:714)
        at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:167)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unexpected termination of the channel
        at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:50)

20-Dec-2013 9:38:13 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Locating server among [htttp://name:8080/]
20-Dec-2013 9:38:13 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connecting to name:45606
20-Dec-2013 9:38:13 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Handshaking
20-Dec-2013 9:38:13 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connected
20-Dec-2013 9:38:13 AM hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread run
SEVERE: I/O error in channel channel
java.io.IOException: Unexpected termination of the channel
        at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:50)
20-Dec-2013 9:38:13 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Terminated
20-Dec-2013 9:38:23 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Locating server among [htttp://name:8080/]
20-Dec-2013 9:38:23 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connecting to name:45606
20-Dec-2013 9:38:23 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Handshaking
20-Dec-2013 9:38:23 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connected
20-Dec-2013 9:38:24 AM hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread run
SEVERE: I/O error in channel channel
java.io.IOException: Unexpected termination of the channel
        at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:50)
20-Dec-2013 9:38:24 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Terminated
```

Comment: I'm getting the same issue. Can I ask, did you ever get it resolved? If not, can I ask, are you using a Mac where the user is not the original administrator of the machine.

Comment: I did a uninstall and installed an older version.

Comment: This behaviour may indicate also the presence of a fascist firewall that is resetting tcp connections after a timeout. You are able to do a build right after enabling the slave? Can you move the slave or the master to another place?

Comment: I had the same problem with an actual jenkins (1.641).<br>
My solution was to restart the Master-Jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

We ran into this problem when updating to Jenkins 2.60.1. That version is the first LTS release to require Java 8 and we made sure to update the master to use Java 8. Unfortunately the slaves wouldn't start, giving the error you report in the title.

The problem turned out to be that the slave nodes were starting using Java 7 and we had to use the "Advanced" button on the node configuration page to make sure the correct Java path was used by the slave nodes

Comment: How were you able to determine it was a Java 7 issue?